# java strings not appending in a file when created

Tags: java

I need your help with the below code , I am not able to append the text (`Hi` in my example). the file is being created and I am having inside of it only 1 `Hi`, however I am looping inside of it ( when I run the cmd I can see it is looping and system printing several hi ) but why i am having in the file 1 `hi` ?

I made sure that this is true 
`fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);`

```
            try
            {

                LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(directory+"/Ant_log.log"));


                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                FileWriter fw = null;
                File file = new File(directory+"/Log-Missing-scripts.txt");

                String line1 ="";
                    while((line1 = rdr.readLine())!= null)               
                    {

                        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }

                        // true = append file
                        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                        System.out.println(rdr.getLineNumber());
                         if (rdr.getLineNumber()== 3) 
                            {
                                System.out.println("Hi");

                        bw.write("Hi");
                        break;
                            }
                    }
                    bw.close();
                    writer.close();


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR : In Log File");

            }
        }
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks it work please added as an answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your `file` and `*Writer` creation code to before the loop, otherwise you are creating new `Writer`s each iteration. Only the last created `Writer` is being closed and flushed